# UIViewController interfaceOrientation always same value

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller

No matter which way i turn the iPad, the viewcontroller.interfaceOrientation always returns 1. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but could it be the orientation lock button is on? :)

Comment: That's actually a great thought! The answer is no, because this is the 4.2 Gold Master, and the button doesn't matter--and the software button is also on--the user interface is definitely rotating. BUT is it possible this is a bug?

Comment: Might be a little in late: have you solved it? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends where your viewcontroller sits in the view heirarchy.

UIWindow should only have a single viewcontroller linked to it (usually a rootViewController) and this is the viewcontroller that responds to the rotation.
If the rootViewController has multiple children viewcontrollers, you'll need to detect the rotation in the rootViewController and pass it on to the relevant viewcontroller

There's a very good programming guide in the online docs about it. If I find the link I'll post it. 
Search my previous posts where I was pointed in the same direction.

Comment: MightyLeader: "If the rootViewController has multiple children viewcontrollers, you'll need to detect the rotation in the rootViewController and pass it on to the relevant viewcontroller". I have such a hierarchy. One VC that is added to the window, he has multiple VC which he has to take care of. The problem is that the interfaceOrientation of the rootViewController has always the correct value but the children have the wrong value. I would like to ask you how do you "pass" it to the relevant viewController

Comment: I agree with krasnyk. the interfaceOrientation property is read-only, so you can't change it in the children

Comment: Hey, it's been a while since I replied and I'm trying to remember the details but do go first to the Apple programming guides for UIViewControllers and the view heirarchy. It's simply explained there. I *think* that you build your hierarchy as follows... Add the rootviewcontrollers view as a subview of the UIWindow, then add your multiple sub-ViewControllers views as subviews of rootviewcontrollers view. Then ensure each viewcontroller has autorotate methods set to allow the various orientations you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to disappear in iOS 6.0.

A workaround could look like this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
{
    UIViewController *rootViewController = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    if (rootViewController) {
        return rootViewController.interfaceOrientation;
    }
    return [super interfaceOrientation];
}
```